# SOLR query with ™ not working

Tags: solr

1 of the products on our website has a product name with a ™ symbol after it. SOLR won't return any results unless I give it the exact title including the ™ symbol. I figured the stemmer would help with this sort of query, but it doesn't seem to help. Is there any way I can get SOLR to not care about those symbols? We are using Lucene.

Comment: What does the analysis chain for the field look like? You probably want to have a filter that removes anything outside of the text you're searching (or that splits the (tm) into its own token).